# JS global variable reseting when js function is called from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I create some markers on a google Map. I call the create marker function from c#

```
  for(int a = 0; a<cpt;a++)
        {
            jsFunc = "myglobalObject.createMarker(" + nearestStations[a][0] + "," + HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("test", true) + ")";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "script" + a, "$(function () {" + jsFunc + "; });", true);
        }
```

My js looks like this :

```
 var markers = [];
    var infoWindowIsSet = false;
    myglobalObject = {

        map: false,
        prev_infowindow: false, 

        initializeMap: function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var adresseConnexion = document.getElementById("tbAdresseDefault").value;
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 6,
                    center: { lat: 46, lng: 1 },
                    language: "en-US",
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                myglobalObject.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);


                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': adresseConnexion }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == 'OK') {

                        myglobalObject.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        myglobalObject.createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, "test");
                        console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
                    } else {
                        alert('Adresse incorrecte ');
                    }
                });






            });
        },

        createMarker: function (position, information) { 
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: myglobalObject.map,

            });
            markers.push(marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {

                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: information });
                if (myglobalObject.prev_infowindow) {
                    myglobalObject.prev_infowindow.close();
                }


                myglobalObject.prev_infowindow = infowindow;
                infowindow.open(myglobalObject.map, this);
                infoWindowIsSet = true;

            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(myglobalObject.map, "click", function () { 
                if (infoWindowIsSet)
                    infowindow.close();

            });

            return marker;

        }
     }
```

As you can see, I have a map variable in "myglobalObject" that I set here :

```
                myglobalObject.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

However, after calling the createrMarker func from C#, the variable map seems to be reseted to "false" so the parts where I need it in createMarker are failing. I tried to put map as a global variable and it still failed. What could I do ?

The .cs code :

```
public string[][] nearestStations = new String[100][];
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parsingXMLDistance();
    }




    public  void parsingXMLDistance()
    {
        double latOfYourStation = double.Parse(GetLatLng(tbAdresseDefault.Text)[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        double lngOfYourStation = double.Parse(GetLatLng(tbAdresseDefault.Text)[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        string latStr, lngStr;
        int cpt = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            nearestStations[j] = new String[1];
        string jsFunc;
        PDV.pdv_liste l = new PDV.pdv_liste();
        l = (litXMLListe("myXMLFile"));

        for (int i = 0; i <l.pdv.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(i + "\r\n");
            if (l.pdv[i].latitude != "" && l.pdv[i].longitude != "") {
                if (DistanceTo(latOfYourStation, lngOfYourStation, double.Parse(l.pdv[i].latitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 100000, double.Parse(l.pdv[i].longitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 100000) < double.Parse(tbDistDefault.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) )
                {
                    latStr = "" + double.Parse(l.pdv[i].latitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 100000;
                    lngStr = "" + double.Parse(l.pdv[i].longitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 100000;
                    latStr = latStr.Replace(',', '.');
                    lngStr = lngStr.Replace(',', '.');
                    nearestStations[cpt][0] = "{lat:" + latStr + ",lng:" + lngStr + "}";

                    cpt++;

                }
            }
        }

       for(int a = 0; a<cpt;a++)
        {
            jsFunc = "myglobalObject.createMarker(" + nearestStations[a][0] + "," + HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("test", true) + ")";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "script" + a, "$(function () {" + jsFunc + "; });", true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I see that you are passing `click` which if you are not aware, most click events in a web page / application, trigger what is known as a `PostBack` to test this.. place break points in your code and after you step past the `myglobalObject.map`, place a breakpoint as well in your `Page_Load` Event.. and see if that gets hit.. this is what I can see just quickly glancing at your code..

Comment: The initializeMap func is called at body onload and there are no problems with the creation of the original marker. And when I call creatermarker from C#, I effectively have an error on the "click" event. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
". I also have an error at the marker creation "InvalidValueError: setMap:". So it confirms that the map variable is reseting. Is there something I can do to keep the "real" value of map ?

Comment: in my opinion you need to show all relevant code in regards to your `.cs` file.. would need to see the header of the .aspx file to how are you setting up the attributes.. for example `CodeFIle`, are you using correct `namespace` you have a lot going on and sounds like you need to start with debugging the code, then fixing each error one at a time.. are you using a `MasterPage`.. lots to question here...

Comment: I added my .cs code. I'm not using a Master page. If there is anything I can tell you for  a better understanding don't hesitate. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think I have an idea of the problem !! I just put a random console.log in my initializeMap func, and it seems that it is displayed after the console.log of the createMarker func. I thought body onload would be executed before the Page_LoadComplete c# function. Is there a way to make a c# function executed after the body onload ?